# Understanding |& in a pipe

Tags: bash

In the bash manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html
it states:

> If ‘`|&`’ is used, `command1`’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to `command2`’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

My question to the community is, what is the actual point of it.   I did a test to     demonstrate why I think it doesn't do anything.

Here I create a valid loop, and then I create an error on the last line:

```
items="frog cat"
for item in $items
do 
echo $item
done

for item i will make error this line
```

So what the manual implies is that unless I use |&, then stderr won't be output in stdout as it's piped into the next command.  So I tested it:

```
## this shows a regular pipe without &.  As you can see stderr gets written anyway
$ ./testing.sh  | grep error
./testing.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `i'
./testing.sh: line 7: `for item i will make error this line'

## this shows a pipe with |& in it.  
$ ./testing.sh  |& grep error
./testing.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `i'
./testing.sh: line 7: `for item i will make error this line'
```

Yeah, stderror is written to the next piped command anyway, without a `&|`.  So what's the point of `|&` then?

Comment: try writing to a file and see what lands there

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your confusion. What do you *expect* to happen in the two cases?

Comment: Note that it's not short for `2>&1`, but for `2>&1 |`. The pipe operator itself is also included in `|&`.

Comment: @ilkkachu that was misquoted from the original documentation. I've corrected it here

Answer (score 7):

stderr is not "written to the next piped command anyway", it is written to stderr which goes to your terminal by default.

The bash reference manual says:

> it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by command1.

Which means stderr will be redirected to stdout before being sent over the pipe.

```
$ cat stderr.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash


echo 'This is an error' >&2
echo 'This is not'
```

When we run this we see the output on stdout as well as stderr:

```
$ ./stderr.sh
This is an error # This is displayed on stderr
This is not # this is displayed on stdout
```

When I redirect stdout to `/dev/null` I only see stderr:

```
$ ./stderr.sh >/dev/null
This is an error
```

Similarly if I redirect stderr to `/dev/null` I see only stdout:

```
$ ./stderr.sh 2>/dev/null
This is not
```

Here we can use this sed command to further illustrate what makes it over the pipe:

```
$ ./stderr.sh | sed 's/^/Via the pipe: /'
This is an error
Via the pipe: This is not

$ ./stderr.sh |& sed 's/^/Via the pipe: /'
Via the pipe: This is an error
Via the pipe: This is not
```

In the first example the error does not get `Via the pipe:` prefixed because it never goes across the pipe.  In the second example it does.

Comment: This just made me more confused.  Why does my example show the error in both cases.  And on your one, I don't understand why when you grep for "not", you still see the line "This iis an error"

Comment: @johnsmith you are grepping for error so it will be shown either way.

Comment: Yeah I still stand completely confused by your response even after the edit, sorry.  If you are saying that stderr is piped without |&, then it only agrees with me that the command |& has not purpose.

Comment: @johnsmith I added some more comments.  Maybe read the bash manual more about stdin, stderr, and stdout.

Comment: You say specifically:
$ ./stderr.sh
    This is an error # This is displayed on stderr
    This is not # this is displayed on stdout

If I grep for not I will still see error since the pipe to grep is currently only looking at stdout


My response to this is, If that's the case, the the error is displayed on stdout, not on stderror? (sorry, the formatting doesn't appear to work on comments)

Comment: @johnsmith No it's displayed on stderr which also goes to your terminal, but does not go over a pipe by default.  The whole purpose of separating stderr and stdout is so you can perform actions/redirections on one without effecting the other.

Comment: I think it'd be clearer if you replace the `grep` command with `sed 's/^/Via the pipe: /'` -- that'll make it much clearer what's going via the pipe vs what's going directly to the terminal.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Good call, updated.

Comment: @johnsmith the confusion is that you think your `grep` is picking up the error, but it actually isn't. Try `./stderr.sh | grep aardvarg` and you will see exactly the same output. That's because the stderr stream is printed to the terminal, but not fed to `grep`.  Since `grep` never sees the lines, it also cannot actually search through them and that's why `| grep aardvarg` produces the same result.